# How do I create a full project from a sandbox project?

Tags: community-official-site

We have created a module for Drupal 8 on drupal.org, but it is a sandbox project. How do I make it a full project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your account elevated to be able to promote a project to full status, meaning you have to go through the project application process if you have not already.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1011698